# One checkbox to disable some CheckBoxFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a MVC program.

I'm using **Razor** language in a View to display a list of Projects (from a Database through Controller/Model) with **CheckBoxFor** :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProjectList.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProjectList[i].Id)
        <li>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ProjectList[i].IsChecked,
        new { id = "projectList_" + i, className = "CheckBoxProject" }) 
        @Model.ProjectList[i].Name</li>
    }
```

This part works fine.

I would like to add another CheckBox to uncheck and disable the previous ChekBoxFor and to prevent them to be checked.
I tried to do this with some JavaScript put **at the end of** the View:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SetBox" value="SetBox" onclick="CheckBoxState(this);">

<script type="text/javascript" onload="loaded=1">
function CheckBoxState(elementRef) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.CheckBoxProject').checked = false;
        document.querySelectorAll('.CheckBoxProject').disabled = true;
};
```

So if I understand what I have done, the **"onclick"** should call the Javascript function called **"CheckBoxState"**. Then grab all the CheckBoxFor having the className **CheckBoxProject**, uncheck and disable them.

When I'm trying it in Firefox, nothing happens when I check the last CheckBox and the page inspector shows a warning something like (is not in english) : ***failed to load script where the source is "http://localhost:..../browserLink"***

I'm not sure how to tell to the View that i'm using Javascript and if **Razor** language is able to works with **Javascript**.

I tried different ways to code the JavaScript depending of what i found on StackOverflow and after several failure i resign myself to ask...

Comment: There are no unchecked or disable attributes, only checked and disabled.. in the error it says it cannot find your local server because you using a colon instead semicolon http://localhost.. but not bad after 2 months of learning to code..

Comment: Thanks @bestinamir, i changed attributes in checked and disabled and i used a semicolon in my description to avoid the link on localhost but it was a mistake :-).
I still have the error message in the page inspector.
I'm going back to my reasearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally i found something that works with jQuery (that i didn't know) :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="SetBox"> <label>Uncheck and disable other Checkbox</label>

<script type="text/javascript">

// Call function when the element with the id = SetBox is clicked
$('#SetBox').click(function(){

    var SetBox = document.getElementById("SetBox");

    if (SetBox.checked)
    {
        // select all checkbox (even SetBox) and unchecked + disabled them
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        $('input:checkbox').prop('disabled', true);

        // select only SetBox and check + enable it.
        $('#SetBox').prop('checked', true);
        $('#SetBox').prop('disabled', false);

    }
    else
    {
        // Make all checkbox available if SetBox is unchecked.
        $('input:checkbox').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

It works with Html.CheckBoxFor().

I still have the warning : failed to load script where the source is "http://localhost:..../browserLink"
But it seems it doesn't matter.

I hope this can help someone later.